# Laravel filesystem sftp cached adapter

Tags: php, laravel, sftp, flysystem

I am struggling with this issue for some time. 
I am using the sftp adapter to connect to another server where i read/write files a lot.

For thumbnail creation i use background jobs with laravel horizon to retrieve pdf contents from the remote sftp server and then generate a jpg and place in local filesystem.

For first setup i need to make around 150k of thumbnails.
When i use a lot of processes in horizon the remote server can't handle this number of connections.

I must limit to max 2 processes at the moment (10 secs~ * 150k~) not optimal.

I want to cache the connection because i know it is possible and probably solves my problem, but can't get it to work:(

The only reference/tutorial/example/docs i could find is

https://medium.com/@poweredlocal/caching-s3-metadata-requests-in-laravel-bb2b651f18f3
https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/advanced/caching/

When i use the code from the example like this:

```
Storage::extend('sftp-cached', function ($app, $config) {
    $adapter = $app['filesystem']->createSftpAdapter($config);
    $store = new Memory();

    return new Filesystem(new CachedAdapter($adapter->getDriver()->getAdapter(), $store));
});
```

I get the error: Driver [] is not supported.

Is there anyone here who can help me a bit further on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears necessary to adjust your configuration:

In your **config/filesystems.php** file, add a 'caching' key to your storage:

```
'default' => [
    'driver' => 'sftp-cached',

    // ...

    'cache' => [
        'store' => 'apc',
        'expire' => 600,
        'prefix' => 'laravel',
    ],
],
```

This example is based on official documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#caching), but it is not described well how the 'store' key is used here (where `memcached` is the example), and you would need to change the implementation of your driver to `new Memcached($memcached);` (with an instance to inject) instead.

In your case, since the *sftp-cached* driver implements `$store = new Memory();`, the cache config must reflect this with `'store' => 'apc'` (which is RAM based cache). Available `'store'` drivers are found in **config/cache.php**.

(If you use APC and get an error message `Call to undefined function Illuminate\Cache\apc_fetch()`, this PHP extension must be installed, see e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/apcu.installation.php)

Finally, I believe the 'prefix' key in **config/filesystems.php** must be set to the same as the cache key prefix in **config/cache.php** (which is `'prefix' => 'cache'` by default).

Comment: Laravel 9's [`Flysystem`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade) no longer supports "cached adapters", what now?

Comment: The "cached adapters" feature would just cache responses, meaning only repeated requests to the same file would get faster, hence OP's 150K requests would remain as slow as before, right?